# Размер FloatingActionButton отличается от preview в Android Studio и в телефоне

Tags: android, android-studio

Не могу настроить размер кнопки FloatingActionButton, передаю картинку "Плюс" который является vector. Меняя размер черного плюса в vectore указывая

```
android:width="64dp"
android:height="64dp"
```

реальный размер при запуске приложения не меняется. Ставил и 64dp и 200dp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/red">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Green"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_add_black_24dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/green"
    android:background="@color/red"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

ic_menu_add_black_24dp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">

<path
    android:fillColor="?colorControlNormal"
    android:pathData="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v3z" />
<path
    android:pathData="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно переопределить значение по умолчанию для параметра design_fab_image_size. Для этого, в ресурсах, в файле dimens добавить значение

```
    <dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">64dp</dimen>
```